# How to check if a post is a sticky post or not in WordPress 5.9?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have try this code see below but needs to check save_post is sticky or not ?

```
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_id) {
    global $wpdb;

    // Here I want to check $post_id is sticky or not 

    $sticky_expiry = get_post_meta($post_id, 'sticky_expiry', true);
    if (empty($sticky_expiry)) {
        $current_date = Date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+10 days'));
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'sticky_expiry', $current_date);
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `is_sticky()` function which returns `true` or `false`.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_sticky/

```
if(is_sticky($post_id)){
 # Do something
}else{
 # Do something else
}
```

In your hook

```
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_id){
    global $wpdb;

    if (is_sticky($post_id)) {
        # Do something
        $sticky_expiry = get_post_meta($post_id, 'sticky_expiry', true);
        if (empty($sticky_expiry)) {
            $current_date = Date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+10 days'));
            update_post_meta($post_id, 'sticky_expiry', $current_date);
        }
    } else {
        # Do something else
    }
}

add_action('save_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
```

Comment: I've checked it but it's not working because is_sticky filter hook is depreciated after Wordpress 5.3 

please check list of hooks https://profbrown.org/p/wp_hooks/hook

Comment: lol! The article you referenced, is talking about wordpress `4.4` :-) at least read the title of the table you referenced. `is_sticky` works on my end wordpress `5.9` and **nowhere**, on the **official documentation (link above)**, does it state that it's deprecated! Please always try to read the official documentation not some random outdated links on the internet!

Comment: I've solved my problem using this **$_POST['sticky'] == 'sticky'** instead of **is_sticky($post_id)**